# How to make collapse cell in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, storyboard, uipickerview

I'm searching for a solution in my code, but I'm not finding specifically what I need.

I have in my Storyboard a UITableViewController with a label in one cell and a picker in another, I already handled the event of changing the label when It's picker change, but  what I still need to do is collapse the picker cell when I click in It's respective label.

Could somebody give me a hand?

---

here`s my code

---

```
import UIKit

class CriarAtividadeTVC: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var pickerAtividades: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var labelAtividadeTipo: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var labelDuracao: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var labelDiaAula: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var comecaAtivLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var terminaAtivLabel: UILabel!

let pickerData = [["Selecione","Plano de Aula", "Tarefa","Trabalho","Prova"]]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerAtividades.delegate   = self
    pickerAtividades.dataSource = self

}

@IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let pickerTag = sender.tag

    if pickerTag == 1{

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
        self.labelDuracao.text = strDate

    } else if pickerTag == 2{

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, dd MMM yyyy"
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
        self.labelDiaAula.text = strDate

    } else if pickerTag == 3{

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm"
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
        self.comecaAtivLabel.text = strDate

    } else if pickerTag == 4{

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm"
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
        self.terminaAtivLabel.text = strDate

    }
}


/* Configuracao dos pickerViews */

func updatePickerLabel(){
    let atividade = pickerData[0][pickerAtividades.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    labelAtividadeTipo.text = atividade
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[component].count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[component][row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    updatePickerLabel()
}

 /* ! Configuracao dos pickerViews */


 /* settings expandable cells */



/* ! settings expandable cells */


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3nU8.png)